# Downloading videos from a flash website

Tags: download, flash

There are those plugins that can capture flash videos from websites like Youtube and others. There's also the browsing cache which keeps the videos and I can copy them somewhere else and have them stored on my computer.

I know of these, but how can I download a video from a website that (I think) is all flash because the address doesn't change wherever you navigate to and so it stays the same when you play a video that's on the website? No plugin I've tried (realplayer, ant video downloadr, IDM) have worked with it and nothing gets cached from that website.

Comment: you need to check the encyption/protection on particular flash content. rtmpe I believe is more troublesome. I am curious myself how to do this - the right tool is required for some particular encrypted content..

Answer (score -1):

Have you ever consider iSkysoft iTube Studio? This is the almighty downloader I'm using and I think it won't be a waste of time to try it. They also provide a freeware for downlading from YouTube. You can check their download speed and the video resolution first :)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. OP did not ask about downloading of videos from YouTube but from different sites where the URL in the browser's address bar does not change.